# .lp format to .zpl

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to convert a program from .lp format to .zpl, but before I convert my actual program I am trying to convert a simple problem to figure out how the .zpl format will work. It is very confusing for me to use .zpl and I could use some help

Here is the program in .lp format

```
 Max : 3 x + 5 y;

 x <= 4;
 2 y <= 12;
 3 x + 2 y <= 18;
 x >= 0;
 y >=0;
```

Here is my attempted conversion to .zpl, I am getting an error for the semicolon in the first line

```
maximize cost : 3*x + 5*y;

subto 1 : x <= 4;
subto 2 : 2*y <= 12;
subto 3 : 3*x + 2*y <= 18;
subto 4 : x >= 0;
subto 5 : y >= 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret the [Zimpl manual](http://zimpl.zib.de/download/zimpl.pdf), section 4, correctly, you need to declare your variables before you define your objective and constraints, i.e. you need to start with:

```
# Variable definitions
var x >= 0;
var y >= 0;
```

*LPsolve* apparently provides support for generating *.zpl* files from *.lp* files using a specific driver, see [this](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Zimpl.htm) link.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Now doing this for my actual program will be quite a hassle!